# CSS fixed drop-down menu behaves weird

Tags: html, css, menu

Anybody understands why my drop-down menu behaves like this? (press on the hamburger to the right in the menu). Obviously, it's the positioning that's the problem somehow, however, I need it to be fixed in the top at the same time so I'm kinda out of options... If I have understood positioning correctly...

```js
$('.hamburger').click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();
 
  if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
  
   /* MENU FADES IN */
   $(".hamburger").removeClass('is-active');
   $("#menu").slideUp(400);
   
   $(".page-1-heading, .play-logo").fadeIn(500);
   $('.respm1, .respm2, .respm3, .respm4, .respm5, .respm6').toggleClass("animate");
   
  } else {
  
   /* MENU FADES OUT */
   $(".hamburger").addClass('is-active');
   $('.respm1, .respm2, .respm3, .respm4, .respm5, .respm6').toggleClass("animate");
   $("#menu").slideDown(400);
   
   $(".page-1-heading, .play-logo").fadeOut();
   
  }
 
 });
```

```css
#responsive-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
 }
.logo-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 12px;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 999;
  font-family: 'Helvetica-Neue', sans-serif;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  width: auto;
  height: 35px;
  
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
 }
.hamburger {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   right: 5%;
   z-index: 999;
   opacity: 1;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition-property: opacity, filter;
   transition-duration: 0.15s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   font: inherit;
   color: inherit;
   text-transform: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
   overflow: visible; 
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#menu a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 4;
  color: #333436;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: calc(13px + 0.3vw);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms ease all;
  -moz-transition: 350ms ease all;
  transition: 350ms ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="responsive-menu">
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="hamburger">
    <img src="http://goodstuffcommunications.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/xheadway-imported-image1.png.pagespeed.ic.rjlAN89gbj.png" class="logo-2" alt="Mountain View">
   </div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="logo-2" alt="Mountain View">
  </div>
   
  <!-- Menu content below -->
  <div id="menu">
   <a href="#">Services</a>
   <a href="#">Clients</a>
   <a href="#">About</a>
   <a href="#">Video</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used float left and right for the logo and menu so only it occur like this. If you give `clear:both` to `#menu` it will fix

```js
$('.hamburger').click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();
 
  if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
  
   /* MENU FADES IN */
   $(".hamburger").removeClass('is-active');
   $("#menu").slideUp(400);
   
   $(".page-1-heading, .play-logo").fadeIn(500);
   $('.respm1, .respm2, .respm3, .respm4, .respm5, .respm6').toggleClass("animate");
   
  } else {
  
   /* MENU FADES OUT */
   $(".hamburger").addClass('is-active');
   $('.respm1, .respm2, .respm3, .respm4, .respm5, .respm6').toggleClass("animate");
   $("#menu").slideDown(400);
   
   $(".page-1-heading, .play-logo").fadeOut();
   
  }
 
 });
```

```css
#responsive-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
 }
.logo-2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 12px;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 999;
  font-family: 'Helvetica-Neue', sans-serif;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  width: auto;
  height: 35px;
  
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
 }
.hamburger {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   right: 5%;
   z-index: 999;
   opacity: 1;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition-property: opacity, filter;
   transition-duration: 0.15s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   font: inherit;
   color: inherit;
   text-transform: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
   overflow: visible; 
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#menu {
        clear: both;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#menu a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 4;
  color: #333436;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: calc(13px + 0.3vw);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms ease all;
  -moz-transition: 350ms ease all;
  transition: 350ms ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="responsive-menu">
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="hamburger">
    <img src="http://goodstuffcommunications.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/xheadway-imported-image1.png.pagespeed.ic.rjlAN89gbj.png" class="logo-2" alt="Mountain View">
   </div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/HP_logo_630x630.png" class="logo-2" alt="Mountain View">
  </div>
   
  <!-- Menu content below -->
  <div id="menu">
   <a href="#">Services</a>
   <a href="#">Clients</a>
   <a href="#">About</a>
   <a href="#">Video</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So easy and elegant solution!